# UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum blocks main thread

Tags: ios, uiimage

i currently recognized that the **first** function call of

```
   UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum
```

blocks the main-thread for about 1 1/2 seconds, even on iphone 4s/ipad2.

i also tried to save it in a separate thread like this:

```
-(void) storeInBackground
{
    NSAutoreleasePool *p = [NSAutoreleasePool new];
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, nil,nil,nil);
    [p release];
}

 ....

 //call
 NSThread* thread1 = [[NSThread alloc] initWithTarget:self
                                                selector:@selector(storeInBackground)
                                                  object:nil];
 [thread1 setThreadPriority:0.1];
 [thread1 start];
 [thread1 release];
```

but still, everything blocked.
After it once has digged its way to the photo album, its fast as instant.

Any clue what to do here?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

okay - unplugging the cable did it! Having a Xcode-run slows it down, using the app w/o debugging its fast as expected.

Answer (score 0):

try dispatch_async, your slow down might be starting up a new thread atm! Good luck

```
dispatch_async( dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0ul), ^{
        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(imageView.image, nil, nil, nil);
    });
```

Comment: nah, the slowdown, as i mentioned, happens only on first call. when i redo the call, also a new thread is dispatched, but the UI is not blocked. the pure starting of a new thread does not lead to those blocks. but thank you.